# UI looks different on Samsung device

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an issue where UI of android application looks different on my Samsung Galaxy S5 comparing to other devices such as Nexus5 or Sony Xperia or others..

I have TextViews which arranged inside a TableLayout. 
Each TextView has rectangle with little stroke drawable background which is defined in separate xml.

The problem is that you can see the stroke of the left side of the rectangle but the right side seems to be hidden like it wider than the screen. 
I tried to load a picture but I don't have enough reputation for this.

As I said, it only happens in my Samsung device while on other devices it looks just fine.

Please refer to the layout xml and to the background drawable xml.

Can anyone explain why this and maybe can advise for a solutions?

Here is layout xml's:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".GpsRecMain" 
android:background="@color/LightGrey">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:stretchColumns="*.*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTimer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/black_text_box"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="00:00"
            android:textColor="@color/YellowGreen"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSpeed"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/black_text_box"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/NUMERIC_ZERO"
            android:textColor="@color/YellowGreen"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDistance"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/black_text_box"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/NUMERIC_ZERO"
            android:textColor="@color/YellowGreen"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

background xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<corners android:radius="0dp" />

<solid android:color="@color/Black"/>
<stroke android:width="3px"
        android:color="@color/YellowGreen"/>

<padding android:top="5dp"
         android:bottom="5dp"/>
```

Thanks in advance!
Moti.

Comment: "I tried to load a picture but I don't have enough reputation for this" -- then upload screenshots elsewhere and link to them from here.

Comment: How about changing to android:layout_width="match_parent" for the topmost RelativeLayout?

Comment: I tried changing the layout attributes like "match_parent" but nothing helped. I will try to load the picture and link to it.

Comment: Hi all, 
Here is an image of how it looks on my S5:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_u6KEV21eGGdG5KREtmcWtESnM/edit?usp=sharing

You can see that the right side looks like it is wider than the screen while the left side is perfect..

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem!!

Well, actually it's not a solution.. but the problem gone when I change the text style form *italic* to regular!

I still can't understand why in italic it looks different so I changed the text to normal style.